# Single page scrollify.js Website is loading a #contact link when entering base url

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Have used scrollify to make a 1 page website using sections, issue is now I have this setup for some reason when entering the site url http://testsiteclash.co.uk it automatically redirects to http://testsiteclash.co.uk/#contact showing the 2nd section first, even though section_1 is loaded above?

The page is laid out as a front-page.php with html markup including the two sections, the second section has a inline php include command.

I created two pages in wordpress admin and named section_1, section_2 and input the relevant codes in wordpress for each page created div id="section_1" Section One /div etc... and set their parent to front-page.php

Thanks in advance

weird thing is I had it working earlier, closed developer down and then when restarted it was like this?

front-page.php

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <article id="section_1">
        <section class='section' data-section-name="devonfoodmovement">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <div class="logo-image">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="text">
                <h1>Devon Food Movement</h1>
                    <h2>Website under construction <br class="textbreak">follow us below on ...</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                    <div class="icon1"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/luke-fearon-853606158/" target="_blank"></a></div>
                    <div class="icon2"><a href="#section_2" class="scrollTo"></a></div>
                    <div class="icon3"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/_u/five_mile_food" target="_blank"></a></div>
                    <div class="icon3m"><a href="instagram://user?username=five_mile_food"></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
    <article id="section_2">
        <section class='section' data-section-name="contact">

        <?php 

        include('form.php');

        ?>
        </section>
    </article>
    <div class="home-btn"><a href="#section_1" class="scrollTo"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

custom.js file with some scroll functions and a function to hide a button not needing to be visible on the first section

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
        $.scrollify({
        section: ".section",
        sectionName : "section-name",
        /*interstitialSection : ".footer-end",*/
        scrollSpeed: 2000

        });
    });

    });

    $.fn.inView = function(inViewType){
    var viewport = {};
    viewport.top = $(window).scrollTop();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + $(window).height();
    var bounds = {};
    bounds.top = this.offset().top;
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
    switch(inViewType){
      case 'bottomOnly':
        return ((bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom) && (bounds.bottom >= viewport.top));
      case 'topOnly':
        return ((bounds.top <= viewport.bottom) && (bounds.top >= viewport.top));
      case 'both':
        return ((bounds.top >= viewport.top) && (bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom));         
      default:     
        return ((bounds.top >= viewport.top) && (bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom));        
    }
    };

    $(document).scroll(function(){
    if($('#section_1').inView( 'both' ) == true ){

        $('.home-btn').fadeOut(500).css('display','none');

    }else if($('#section_1').inView( 'both' ) == false ) {

        $('.home-btn').fadeIn(500).css('display','block');

    }

    });

    $(document).ready(function (){
    $(".scrollTo").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
    }, 1000);
    });
    });
```

form.php

```
        <?php include('form_process.php');
        /*if (isset($_POST['contact-submit'])){

            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $privatekey = "secretkeygoogle";

            $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADOR']);

            $data = json_decode($response);

            if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {

            }else{

            }


        }*/

    ?>
    <div class='grey'>
        <div class="container-contact">
            <form id="contact" method="post">
                <div id="column-contact-left">
                <div class='contact-logo'></div>
                <h3>Contact the Devon Food Movement</h3>
                <fieldset>
                    <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name1" value="<?= $name ?>" autofocus>

                </fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                <fieldset>
                    <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >

                </fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                </div>
                <div id="column-contact-right">
                <fieldset>
                    <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" value="<?= $message ?>" tabindex="3" ></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="needtoinput" ></div>
                <span class="success"><?= $success; ?></span>
                <fieldset>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Helps if you have the developer console running:

`Scrollify warning: Section names can't match IDs - this will cause the browser to anchor.`

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks, I just changed the section class from section to section-class and it is sill anchoring to the bottom?

Comment: Not sure if you've uploaded to your live URL. However, the scrollify warnings still remain...

Comment: and the error message is still there?

Comment: yes, have uploaded

Comment: Press F12 on your browser. Learn how to use the developer tools in your browser. It will pay dividends.

Comment: Im using developer, thats how i can still see the error message coming up

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis: added an answer. see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the page

one scrollify plugin has wrong classname.

two you have autofocus set on input type, which will make the browser to automatically scroll to that section.

You can use inView utility function that you have written to set the focus on the input type onscroll when the element is in viewport. I can't test this bit. you can let me know if this solves your purpose.

```
  else if($('#section_1').inView( 'both' ) == false ) {
        $('.home-btn').fadeIn(500).css('display','block');          
        $('input[name="name1"]').focus();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you took off auto focus and now it works, thanks again